# retrieving JSON from Response in Jest Node.js test

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm testing a Node/Express app with Jest. I get a 200 code from this Jest test, but nothing for the JSON response.

```
import * as httpMocks from 'node-mocks-http';
import * as ctrlCars from '../src/controllers/cars';

    describe('Test Cars', () => {
        it('should GET car by ID', () => {
            const request = httpMocks.createRequest({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/cars',
                params: {
                    id: 2
                }
            });
            const response = httpMocks.createResponse();
            const next = function(err) { 
              console.log('resultNext: ', response._getData()); 
            };

            ctrlReels.getCar(request, response, next);

            // TODO
            console.log('result: ', response.statusCode);
            console.log('result: ', response.statusMessage);
            console.log('resultData: ', response._getData());
        });
    });
```

The examples I've found online use ._getData() to get the data and then parse it as JSON, but in my test resultData returns nothing and resultNext isn't outputted at all.

Comment: @DavidR you mean outside the context of the test? yes, I use Postman and I know the route is working

Answer (score 1):

After much googling, I found the answer so I'm going to answer my own question for the next person that finds it (https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http/issues/73). There were actually two issues in my case.

1. I wasn't exporting my dev environment variables in the same terminal as I was running the test. My Node app couldn't connect to my DB because I didn't export the user and password. This was being hidden by the second issue.
2. I needed to add EventEmitter to the test to catch the 'send' event and then display that data.

   import * as httpMocks from 'node-mocks-http';

   import * as ctrlReels from '../src/controllers/cars';

   import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

   describe('Test Cars', () => {
       it('should GET car', done => {
           const request = httpMocks.createRequest({
               method: 'GET',
               url: '/cars',
               params: {
                   id: 2
               }
           });
           const response = httpMocks.createResponse({eventEmitter: EventEmitter});
           const next = function(err) {
               console.error('Test error: ', err);
           };

   ```
   ctrlReels.getCar(request, response, next);
   response.on('end', () => {
       console.log('end');
       console.log(response._getData());
       done();
     });
   response.on('send', () => {
       console.log('send');
       console.log(response._getData());
       done();
   });
   ```

   });
   });

This example outputs the data twice. Once for the send event and once for the end event.

Note: I don't know what's going on with the code formatting. I tried... I really did.